# Jquery UI DatePicker CSS Files

Tags: jquery-ui, themes, datepicker

I started integrating jquery ui datepicker in my page.

I included the js files:

```
jquery-1.5.1.js
jquery.ui.core.js
jquery.ui.widget.js
jquery.ui.datepicker.js
```

and CSS Files:

```
jquery.ui.datepicker.css
```

But it resulted out datepicker without the background...

what am i missing on it?

After i manually add : 
`.ui-datepicker{background-color: silver;}`

it shows like:

http://outsourcingnepal.com/general-images/shot1.jpg

Comment: Did you include the CSS files before the JS files?

Comment: Are other styles working? Can you provide link to live site?

Comment: @raisen: yes i did include the css file beofre js files.

Comment: @dampe: other styles like showing the month calendar and other are fine.... Its still in development phase... not uploaded yet

Comment: How about adding jquery-ui.css?

Comment: Default datepicker doesn't use images for bg afaik.

Comment: i don't find jquery-ui.css in my source pack... but still its working there in demo one... but not in my copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved unpackaing all the files once more... i hope some files were missing

Answer (score 0):

Check the datepicker.css if there is style definition for the element with missing background. If not..just check the element in firebug (or similar tool) and add your own style. There probably will be already a class, so just add your style in your stylesheet, or add it into detepicker.css.

Answer (score 0):

For styling only the DatePicker, these are the necessary stylesheet files:

```
~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css
~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css
~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css
```

or the minified ones:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.core.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.css" />
```